# Using sub reference with Moose builder

Tags: perl, moose

Moose documentation mentions that `builder` property for attribute in class definiton should be a string that contains name for function that will be called to build relevant attribute. Simple testing however shows that sub reference works as well:

```
has 'some_attribute' => (
    is => 'ro',
    lazy => 1,
    builder => sub {
        require SomeModule::Heavy;
        return SomeModule::Heavy->new($_[0]);
    },
);
```

Did I miss something in docs? Is usage of sub reference officially supported for `builder`?

Comment: The section in the docs noting that builders get called by name is in https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod#Builders-allow-subclassing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Moose manual](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod#Default-and-builder-methods) says:

> You can also provide a subroutine reference for `default`. This reference will be called as a method on the object. […] As an alternative to using a subroutine reference, you can supply a `builder` method for your attribute. This has several advantages. First, it moves a chunk of code to its own named method, which improves readability and code organization. Second, because this is a named method, it can be subclassed or provided by a role.

So, if you use subroutine reference for `builder` then you lose these advantages. I think subroutine reference works as side effect and has no practical application.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be it, though I'd argue if poluting package namespace with arbitrary pseudo-private named functions is an "advantage". Sub-class/role still'd need to inspect your class because it can't reliably guess how you name your builders and it could replace `default` just as easily.